# If I have a custom dialog window is it ok to create a new one each time?

Tags: c#, dialog

```
myDialog d = new myDialog(); 
d.ShowDialog();
```

Once my dialog processes some input, I do a

```
this.Close();
```

from within the dialog class.

then back in my main window, I check a variable i.e.

```
if (d.OK = true)
{
//do stuff
}
```

Is this ok if several of these dialogs will be created as the program is used? Or should I use a static variable on my main form that references the same dialog? Does it make a difference?

Comment: If you use the exact same dialog each time, `.Hide()` and `.ShowDialog()` will be suffice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this pattern and your dialog will always be correctly disposed

```
using(myDialog d = new myDialog())
{
     if(DialogResult.OK == d.ShowDialog())
     { 
         //do stuff (for example, read some property values on the dialog)
         if(d.ExecuteSomeAction == true)
              // Do some action -> call a database query or something.....
     } 
}
```

Using a static variable to maintain the dialog from disposing (and in that case you should call `this.Hide()` not `this.Close()` is, in my opinion, a bad practice, unless you need to keep track of a 'state condition' or propose to your users their last inputs. You should also be very carefull in closing the static variable when you app close.

Comment: Note that in some cases he will need to specify in the dialog what DialogResult to return.

Answer (score 1):

Once disposed a Form can not be reused, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider this:

```
using (myDialog d = new myDialog())
{
   d.ShowDialog();

   if (d.OK)
   {
      // do stuff
    }
}
```

After the last brace you are sure your dialog is being disposed properly and all memory is freed.
Like this you can use the dialog as much as you want. Using a `using` is a good practice and can be used on all objects implementing the `IDisposable` interface.

See [using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).